# Can "fellow writers" live in different times?

Tags: word-usage

I may be mistaken but I usually use "fellow workers", "fellow players" or "fellow actors" when they share a profession at the same time. According to lexico.com, "fellow" as an adjective means "sharing a particular activity, quality, or condition with someone or something." Now I wonder if I can use "fellow writers" to refer to two or more writers who lived in different times. For example, can I say, "Virginia Woolf and her fellow writers", while by the latter I mean her predecessors?

Comment: I would think the quoted definition makes it clear. "Fellow" does not have to be a synonym of "contemporary."

Comment: I can understand your problem; the definition seems over-broad. 'Hitler and his fellow rulers in Europe' seems overstretched. With 'fellow writers' as here, I wouldn't expect that to include Ruth Gruber, say. I'd expect more cohesiveness within the group.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not with "fellow," but that you really intend a more particular commonality. "Virginia Woolf and her fellow writers": Yes, includes P.G. Wodehouse, Aeschylus, Stephen King, and my cousin who's "working on his novel." "Virginia Woolf and her fellow modernist writers"/"... and her fellow feminist writers"/"... her fellow essayists" perhaps zero in on the point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the word “fellow” cannot be used of those from other times as the fellows need to be contemporaneously present.

The common theme in all the examples in a fair-sized set of entries for “fellow” in the OED is this idea of being contemporaneous and that the fellows be linked in some way:

OED:

> **Etymology**: < early Scandinavian filaga , felaka partner, Old Icelandic félagi business partner, trading partner, shareholder, companion, comrade, spouse
>
> **I. A partner, companion, or peer of another specified person, and related senses.
> †1. a. A person who shares with another specified person in a particular possession, office, undertaking, etc.; a partner, colleague, collaborator. Also: a person united with another specified person in pursuit of a common end; an ally.** *obsolete*

Whereas there is the possibility of the etymological fallacy, the meaning of companionship and co-operation seems to have lasted through the years.

> Compounds
>
> **C1.** Appositive, passing into adj. **Equivalent to even adj.1 and n.2 Compounds 2a, co- prefix 5. Cf. joint adj. 2a. … Such compounds are usually formed with a hyphen or as two words, although in early use single word forms also occur. From the 20th cent. formation as two words is more common.**
>
> **a. Designating a person or (occasionally) a thing associated with another specified person or thing in companionship or cooperation, as fellow lodger, fellow passenger, fellow prisoner, fellow workman, etc. See also fellow helper n. at Compounds 2, fellow-knower n. at Compounds 2, fellow soldier n., fellow traveller n.**
>
> 1439–41   in J. A. Kingdon Arch. Worshipful Company of Grocers (1886) II. 257   *John Lurchun and his Felaw executowris of Robert Chichele.*
>
> 1968   Jrnl. Marriage & Family 30 402   *Northern and southern women now have almost equal chances of marrying a fellow student.*
>
> 2015   Advertiser (Adelaide) (Nexis) 1 Sept. 6   *There were a number of issues that you and your fellow prisoners were aggrieved about.*
>
> **b. Designating a person or thing that belongs to the same class or category as another specified person or thing, as fellow bishop, fellow Christian, fellow human being, fellow planet, fellow sinner, etc. See also fellow creature n.**
>
> a1475   in A. Clark Eng. Reg. Godstow Nunnery (1906) ii. 637 (MED)   *Iohn of lee & his felowis Iustices.*
>
> 2009   H. Kubernik Canyon of Dreams x. 162/1   *And there she was, a fellow musician and a great beauty.*
>
> **c. Designating a person or (occasionally) a thing which has the same relationship as another specified person or thing to a third party, institution, polity, place, etc., as fellow disciple, fellow employee, fellow member, fellow servant, fellow townsman, etc. See also fellow citizen n., fellow countryman n., fellow-heir n.**
>
> 1526   Bible (Tyndale) Coloss. iv. f. cclxvii   *Tichicos.., which is a..felowe servaunt [Gk. σύνδουλος] in the lorde.*
>
> 1991   Bicycling Feb. 98/1   *He returned my grin and greeted me like I was a fellow townsman.*
>
> 2008   New Yorker 5 May 78/3   *Pearl has been enlisted..to spy on her fellow-employees.*

It is interesting to see "fellow" as an appositive.

In such a phrase as "Dickens and his fellow Victorian writers" I would take to mean that, in order to qualify for the epithet, the "fellows" would have to be alive and writing at the same time as Dickens, **and** have written on a similar theme, **and** all have lived in the reign of Victoria.

I would not see, for example, Charles Darwin as one of Dicken's fellows (not the same subject matter), nor Jane Austin (not Victorian).

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. C1 would seem to me to require only a uniting factor. Thus "Shakespeare and his fellow bards, from Homer to Bob Dylan."

Comment: To be clear, I'm distinguishing between "fellows," without qualifier, which relies upon context and common sense as well as carries a sense of "peerage" (which makes it doubtful that Bob Dylan is among Shakespeare's "fellows") and "fellow [noun]s," which lets us draw an enclosing line around otherwise disparate parties.

Comment: @AndyBonner *Shakespeare and his fellow bards, from Homer to Bob Dylan.* It would be good if you could show a reliable source for such a use. I would certainly suggest it to the OED.

Comment: This is definitely an attempt to read something into the dictionary that isn't there. Fellow implies commonality or some kind of brotherhood, and often that will mean people in the same place and time, but brotherhoods can exist across time and space. For example in *The Atom Story*, Joseph George Feinberg, 1953 "the glorious and living literature of Chaucer, Shakespeare, Dickens and their fellow writers". Perhaps there is a sense that all writers are contemporaries because they're all still living through their work, but it's plainly across history.